# how to refresh the model after updating the content of it?

Tags: ember.js

After adding an item to a Json, I'm listing those items by calling them to a model. But the item takes some time to process (and get added to the array). How do I refresh the model (or the View) so that I don't need to hit refresh to update the list and view the new item listed?

I apologize for the rookieness of my question, I'm fairly new to ember. Thanks in advance for any help.

```
 model: function (transition) {

    return Ember.$.getJSON(ENV.apiUrl + 'get_feeds').then(
        function(response) {
            return response;
        })
            });
}
```

Comment: You should consider using emeber data - it takes care of the bindings for you

Comment: `function(response) { return response; }` is the identity function--in other words, it does nothing, and can be removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an `Ember.Object` to represent this model in your `models` folder (assuming Ember-CLI). In the `then` function of your `$.getJSON`, create an instance of this `Ember.Object`.

```
import Ember from 'ember';
import SomeModel from 'app_name/models/some-model';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function (transition) {

        return Ember.$.getJSON(ENV.apiUrl + 'get_feeds').then(
            function(response) {
                return SomeModel.create(response);
            });
    }
});
```

The create function takes a javascript object as its lone parameter and assigns all its properties to the object it's constructing. The advantage of using an `Ember.Object` as oppsoed to just a POJO is that `Ember.Object` extends the `Observable` mixin and thus two-way binding can be achieved. Meaning, if in your associated template, you have `{{model.someProp}}` and then asynchronously update your model's `someProp` via an ajax call (triggered however), the DOM will automatically update due to two way binding. Take advantage of the power Ember offers. Ember Data isn't necessary for this btw